# python NameError variable already set to global

Tags: python, global

I want to Change the Position of a spinbox and an entry field by clicking on a button.
Clicking on the button Triggers this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "GUI.py", line 79, in changesite
if (site==0):
NameError: global name 'site' is not defined
```

My code is this here:

```
                else:
    w = Spinbox(dialog, from_=5, to=getmodulo(ceiling), increment = 5.0, state='readonly',font = "bold")
    e = Entry(dialog,font = "bold")
    e.place(x=390,y=120)
    w.place(x=20,y=120)
    site = 0
    def changesite():
        global site
        if (site==0):
            e.destroy()
            w.destroy()
            ws = Spinbox(dialog, from_=5, to=getmodulo(ceiling), increment = 5.0, state='readonly',font = "bold")
            es = Entry(dialog,font = "bold")
            es.place(x=20,y=120)
            ws.place(x=390,y=120)
            site = 1
        if (site ==1):
            ws.destroy()
            es.destroy()
            w = Spinbox(dialog, from_=5, to=getmodulo(ceiling), increment = 5.0, state='readonly',font = "bold")
            e = Entry(dialog,font = "bold")
            e.place(x=390,y=120)
            w.place(x=20,y=120)
            site = 0
```

As you see I use global for site, so how can I fix this error? I don't know how to do at the Moment.
All the best;

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? Namely what kind of block is this (indentation suggests this code is inside of something) and where is the `changesite()` function called.

Comment: changesite() is called from the command by clicking on a button. I think the code around this snippet isn't needed.

Comment: Not the whole code, I just want to see if, for example, `site` is declared in an else statement or a class/function definition. The code you've shown us won't cause any errors (except for IndentationError on line 2)

Comment: You can define a Class with the class attribute `site` (it'll work as a static variable)

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a wild guess, since you do not show us all of your code, but I could reproduce the problem when the "global" variable is not really global, but defined in an enclosing function.

Minimal example:

```
# global f is expected here...
def foo():
    f = 42 # ... but defined here
    def bar():
        global f
        f = f + 1 # this causes a NameError
    bar()
foo()
```

Instead, you could make `site` a member of the class (if any), or even of the outer method (like `name_of_outer_method.site`), or make it truly global, or use a modifyable wrapper type.